# How can i logout from twitter from my application using fabric framework in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

In my iOS application, i am integrate twitter login using **fabric framework**  “**TWTRComposer**”.
it is working fine when first time login and post twit on twitter.
but i m not able to done logout from twitter in my application.
and second time when  i am try to login. twitterlogin view controller not able to open.
so pls any one can give me solution for successfully **login and logout** from my application using **TWTRComposer**

Comment: Twitter.sharedInstance().logOut() is the method for logout

Comment: i was tried this "Twitter.sharedInstance().logOut()". but it was not working

Comment: so...is it not working????

Comment: no buddy.. its not working

Comment: you said first time all works good...but second time when you tried to login the problem occurs...so did you check using breakpoint...method is actually called or not on second time

Comment: Hope you will find same issue described here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28774762/3202193 This is the answer of question.

Comment: yeah exactly my problem you got it.
 i checked this breakpoint way also. 
 i think twitter logout successfully not done. so when second time come in application login view controller of twitter not opened

Comment: Same issue discussed here : https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-api-loginwithcompletion-and-logout/32228/8 try to find out the solution from there

Comment: thanks guys, thanks a lot for help.
still one question is, any other solution for logout without manually account delete from iPhone setting ?

Answer (score 2):

The `[Twitter sharedInstance]` object have two method to logout : logOut and logOutGuest.

Here is the link to the docs: [Twitter object iOS reference](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twitter)

Just FYI you can check if the user is logged in using the session parameter like below

`[[Twitter sharedInstance] session]`

If session is nil then they are not logged in.

Try below thing if above thing not work, It might be possible cookies still exist.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
       // put a check here to clear cookie url which starts with twitter and then delete it
         [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
```

Comment: how do you call this method though? i have tried to set up an IBAction that checks if the TW session is active, if so, [[Twitter sharedInstance] logOut];, but nothing happens, it kicks straight to my else statement that says user already logged in

Comment: how would you put the check to clear the cookie url and delete it?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logOut]
```

and

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logOutGuest]
```

will not work, since as per the docs:

> Deletes the local Twitter user session from this app. This will not
>   remove the system Twitter account nor make a network request to
>   invalidate the session.

So additionally, you need to invalidate the token returned by oauth. You can get help from [twitter's](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/invalidate/token) docs. Use this REST webservice in order to invalidate token. Pass `access_token` to the post request.

As per the link,

> Allows a registered application to revoke an issued OAuth 2 Bearer
>   Token by presenting its client credentials. Once a Bearer Token has
>   been invalidated, new creation attempts will yield a different Bearer
>   Token and usage of the invalidated token will no longer be allowed.

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: could you update your answer to possibly show how exactly to invalidate the token to clear the twitter session? been driving me nuts lol

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
  [[Twitter sharedInstance] logOut];
```

Comment: this method does not work. care to explain how to use it? we all know that this is the method twitter suggests to use on the dev.twitter site...

Answer (score 0):

Removing cookies - doesnt help.

I invent my own flow for relogin:

(*I need user email to further login so only WebBasedLogin*)

```
// Get first twitter acc (check if it exists etc...)
.....

// This method will be used if user the same
TWTRLoginMethod loginMethod = TWTRLoginMethodSystemAccounts;

// Check if it is the Previous twitter user (whom was stored in userDefaults)
if (![[STLUserDataManager lastTwitterUser] isEqualToString:[firstTwitterAccount username]])
{
// if user is new - ForceLogin
    loginMethod = TWTRLoginMethodWebBasedForceLogin;
}

// inside completion
{
 ...
// Store userName in userDefaults
[STLUserDataManager storeTwitterUser:[firstTwitterAccount username]];
}
```