# Unable to deauthorize Twitter session

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using ParseUI for Facebook and twitter authentication. SDK version 1.17.1

Below is my scenario

User has logged in via Facebook using an email id xyz
He tries Twitter login that also uses same email id ie xyz
I am checking error of email already used and show error message to user. At this stage try to deauthorize Twitter using below code (in didLoginUser method)

```
let twitter = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()
twitter?.deauthorizeInBackground()
```

At this stage ParseUI login view is displayed. If i click Twitter button, i don't get Twitter login page but browser seems to be reusing previously authenticated session.

I want Twitter login page displayed after deauthorization. How do i achieve it?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the cookies for session to achieve this.

Original solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925484/430690) by @Will-Von-Ullrich

```
if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
                                for cookie in cookies {

                                    if cookie.domain.contains("twitter")
                                    {
                                        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
                                        logger.info("Twitter cookie deleted")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```