# iOS - Correct logOut from Twitter SDK

Tags: ios, twitter

I have app with social login. When user press on Twitter button, I call method:
`[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion`...

After that, if this is first start, Twitter show me a modal webView with login fields. 
To logOut I call `[[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore logOutUserID:[Twitter sharedInstance].session.userID]`.
But, next time, when i call `[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion`, Twitter SDK download previous user info.

Is there any way to clean Twitter cache (or where user login data is saved) in my app?

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610620/twitter-fabric-login-button-only-working-once/31399025#31399025

Answer (score 1):

**I can not**. 
iOS automatically saves the data and when calling the method "logInWithCompletion" returns saved account

Thank you for the link, @EI Captain

Answer (score 0):

For logIn use method

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithMethods:TWTRLoginMethodWebBasedForceLogin completion:{}]
```

Parameter TWTRLoginMethodWebBasedForceLogin

- Presents a web view that doesn't use any cached sessions
  from Safari. Allows the developer to provide multi-user
  functionality with several Twitter accounts.

Comment: This is no more available inTwitter kit  SDK 3.0